# Use Boost Library with Bada

Tags: bada

How can i use boost library with bada SDK?
I have already build boost library on my pc.
I found this [hints](http://developer.bada.com/article/Using-Static-Libraries-in-bada-Applications), but i don't understand very well what i should exactly to do.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

To get your Bada project using BOOST, you should do the following:

- Install [BOOST](http://www.boost.org/users/download/) on your PC.
- Set BOOST environment variable referencing the base directory of the BOOST directory
- Edit your Bada project properties : Go in C/C++ Build > Settings > Directories
- Add "${BOOST}/" to include paths

Then include BOOST headers (for example `#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>` ) and use BOOST type